# Why did Pakistan stop importing tanks from the USA after M-48 Pattons?

Tags: united-states, china, pakistan, weapons

What made Pakistan stop importing M-48 Pattons from the USA and start importing tanks from China?

Comment: What research have you done on this?  Are you sure they used to import 48's from the US and not some 3rd party?  Are you sure they are getting tanks  from china?

Comment: @SoylentGray, are you serious?

Comment: Very.  It may be common knowledge in your circle but I can assure it is not in mine.

Comment: Voting to close - please edit your questions to include references to back your claims.